# Software to Mind Map Dependencies

Tags: architecture, dependencies, mindmapping

I'm putting together something I'll soon release as OSS and I wanted to make a map of dependencies to get a clearer idea of the big picture. I ended up making the mind map myself using pen and paper:

[image: Mind Map]

This is something I wish I could do more often, but mapping bigger projects manually is too troublesome (and virtually impossible due to the size of the sheet) and since I can't find any mind mapping software that fits my needs and allows me to display the map in the visual structure I want I often leave the mind maps in my mind alone, no visual representation whatsoever...

Can anyone **suggest a good mind mapping software that allows me to do something like the above**? I've tried **[FreeMind](http://freemind.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)** and **[XMind](https://www.xmind.net/)** so far but their visual structure is *too rigid* for what I need.

Comment: Did you ever find a satisfactory solution?

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/)?

It does not have a WYSIWYG IDE, but it's very flexible.

**EDIT**:

If you are looking for something easier, I would highly recommend [Gliffy](http://www.gliffy.com/). Take a look at their examples.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't tried graphviz it seems awfully powerful but also very complex, I'm looking for something that has a small learning curve.

Comment: You're welcome. I have edited my reply, including a second suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

[Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.org), in addition to automatically generating HTML documentation and class hierarchy diagrams, is also capable of generating complete dependency graphs and call graphs for your libraries and applications. You just need to configure it appropriately so that it will generate the type of documentation that you want.

Note that Doxygen uses [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/) and its [dot tool](http://www.graphviz.org/cgi-bin/man?dot) to generate those graphs. While you could use GraphViz directly, Doxygen is able to parse the code and extract the necessary information needed in order to pass it along to GraphViz/Dot and have it generate the appropriate graph visualizations.

If you are looking to create these graphs before you have a product... in other words, to plan out your code rather than to document it, then you might be interested in a UML design tool such as [ArgoUML](http://argouml.tigris.org/). You can use it to diagram inheritance as well as dependencies, and you can generate code from the UML diagrams.

If you want to create these kind of diagrams manually, and you just want a general-purpose drawing tool, then [OpenOffice](http://www.openoffice.org/) has a drawing tool, although I have found that making it look nice can be quite difficult.

Comment: I'll give Doxygen a try, however I visited their website and couldn't find any real example of dependencies map. UML seems to be what I'm looking for but I don't understand how to use it, I even bought a lousy book a few years ago on UML modeling but ended up learning nothing with it. Have you had any experience with ArgoUML or any alternatives (http://alternativeto.net/desktop/argouml/)?

Comment: Also, if you happen to know any good UML online tutorial that's worth reading please share it. And yes, I'll be re-reading the Wikipedia entry. =)

Answer (score 4):

- There are plenty of mind-mapping tools nowadays, such as
  **mindmeister.com** and **lucidcharts.com**. Some allow collaboration.
- For block based diagrams try **gliffy.com** and **draw.io**
  which is free.
- For network graphs try **evergraph.io** which is free as well.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if you might be better suited with a general-purpose diagramming software - while it might not have *quite* as fluid an approach to specifically mind-mapping, it should be far more versatile in terms of how to display them.

Comment: I agree that I probably would. I've heard very good things about Visio (and I just love these diagrams: http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html), but I believe it's rather expensive. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You could use IHMC CmapsTool a free concept mapping software. It does not restrict you to a tree-like structure, a very easy to learn tool, it allows you to label links between items (concepts) so your maps should be easy to understand by other people. Multiplatform Java based.

http://cmap.ihmc.us/conceptmap.html

Other similar free concept mapping software although harder to use are:

Compendium (look on Wikipedia) and VUE (See Wikipedia page)

Answer (score 0):

[FreeMind](http://freemind.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) is a good choice for putting whatever you need to the computer.
It also exports mind maps to png, jpeg and other formats.
I have used it before and I recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned both FreeMind and XMind, but had reservations about their rigidity.  yEd (https://www.yworks.com/products/yed) might be the perfect fit; I've had excellent results with it.  yEd is free.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer [Mind Vector](https://www.mindvectorweb.com/) - A popular mind mapping app. Because it has something highlight features that will solve the problem you faced on mind map.